# Unit test architecture with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I try to think of an optimal architecture of unit-tests with pytest framework, which will let me maintain and expand my code easily, but I faced some difficulties. Let me expalin a problem.

I have around 100 individual tasks. Each task has its own unit-tests (e.g. 5 tests per task).

As an argument I recieve raw python code. After that I run this code using exec function and then pass this code to unit-tests.

I want to organise my unit-tests in the way that I could easily remove tasks and appropriate unit-tests / easily add new tasks and unit-tests and so on.

The problem is that now I store tests for each task in separate file. I name files with task id, e.g. test_1.py. But if this ID changes for some reason, I will have problems.

```
--- Test Folder

------test_1.py

---------test_1 
---------test_2 
---------test_3

------test_2.py

---------test_1 
---------test_2 
---------test_3
```

Do you have any ideas how to orginise my unit-tests in the most competent way?

Comment: What's a task? Why might its ID change (and why would renaming the file be a problem if it did)? Why are you having to exec code?

Comment: Yea I'm also wondering why you will have problem, when changing the task id? I think the way you arrange your tests should work just fine and makes sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I recieve user's code from frontend and I need to check it - that's why I user exec. As for ID - in fact, old IDs won't change, because these IDs match IDs from database. But I'm interested in whether it's an appropriate way to organise unit-tests or they should be organised in a different way.